# Is a Command Line Bootable USB Possible?

Tags: windows, command-line, usb, bootable-media

I understand how to create a bootable Windows/Linux OS USB, however, when that USB is booted up, the whole operating system loads on the computer.

My question is, what if I do not want all of that to happen? Honestly, I just want a simple command to run when I boot from my USB. A Batch file or a PowerShell file would suffice.

I do not know if this is possible, and I have looked for an answer, but to no avail. I just want to know if I can run a batch/CMD file, when I boot from my USB. And if it is not possible, what is the next best thing?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Rufus and their FreeDOS option?

What all are you trying to accomplish? Your computer NEEDS an operating system to run, whether it's Windows, MS-DOS, Linux, OSX, Novell, etc. You can even use the UEFI shell on some systems.

Comment: I do understand that a computer needs an OS to run, but I was just wondering if the USB can be used to run a function on it, without changing the OS. I can understand if this is not possible, but I just want to know.

Comment: You can, and Rufus gives you a copy of FreeDOS for running batch files. If you're looking for anything more (i.e. access to Windows 7 tools), then we need more information in your question